# How do I insert a column after the first column in a CSV and then populate it with a single value?

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV that has info and a format similar to the info I am providing below as an example:

```
FileType     clientid     cust_name     cust_num     cust_email
SL           137856       Jim Smith     A756         jim@aol.com
SL           137856       Paul Yung     H568         yungster@yahoo.com
SL           137856       Tim Jeffries  T478         timbo@gmail.com
SL           137856       Tom Reedy     N290         reddy76@gmail.com
```

I want to insert a column after the first one and populate it with one string like this:

```
FileType    dealerid    clientid     cust_name     cust_num     cust_email
SL          RB6745      137856       Jim Smith     A756         jim@aol.com
SL          RB6745      137856       Paul Yung     H568         yungster@yahoo.com
SL          RB6745      137856       Tim Jeffries  T478         timbo@gmail.com
SL          RB6745      137856       Tom Reedy     N290         reddy76@gmail.com
```

I'm currently stuck on this piece of code, which I have used in the past to append a column to the beginning of a csv file and I modified it slightly to try to make it work for my purposes:

```
with open(id_append_file_path, 'rb') as inf, open(append_file_path + 'new' + append_file_name, 'wb') as outf:
     reader = csv.DictReader(inf)
     fields = reader.fieldnames
     fields.insert(1, 'dealerid')
     writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, fields)
     writer.writeheader()
     for node, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
         row['dealerid'] = dealer_id
         writer.writerow(row)
```

But these are the results I see when I open the new CSV:

```
FileType    dealerid    clientid      cust_name     cust_num             cust_email
SL          RB6745      Jim Smith     A756          jim@aol.com
SL          RB6745      Paul Yung     H568          yungster@yahoo.com
SL          RB6745      Tim Jeffries  T478          timbo@gmail.com
SL          RB6745      Tom Reedy     N290          reddy76@gmail.com
```

I'm still fairly new to Python, so maybe I'm missing something. I'm using Python 2.7.11.

Comment: Aside: if you're new to Python, it's a better idea to start with modern Python -- Python 2 is only a few years away from being end-of-lifed.

Comment: @DSM What I mean by new is that I have been programming in Python off and on for a couple of years, but mainly writing scripts. Thanks for the heads up. Most of my scripts are written in 2.7. Looks like it is time to update them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying the `fieldnames` list that the reader is using before you read from it:

```
 fields = reader.fieldnames
 fields.insert(1, 'dealerid')
```

Replace this by `fields = list(reader.fieldnames)` or `fields = reader.fieldnames[:]` or something which will make a copy, so you're not mutating the original.

Comment: That worked. Just so I understand, when I was mutating the original header name I was overwriting the key that DictWriter uses to keep column positions, right?

Comment: You were modifying the list that Dict**Reader** uses to track column positions.  `fields = reader.fieldnames` doesn't make a copy, it just says 'the name "fields" now refers to the same list that "reader.fieldnames" refers to'.

Comment: Excellent answer! The [`csv` module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/41d4ec8d6be259655d3efd08f3a4c66a8b7f9537/Lib/csv.py#L104-L124) shows `DictReader` creates its dict by doing `d = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, row))`.  If fieldnames is longer than the row, it adds the extra fieldnames to the dict using a default value (usually `None`).